# Need help with choosing the Rom for ZebPad 7t100

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, rom

Without my knowledge my father bought a [ZebPad 7t100](http://www.zebronics.com/products/tablet/zebpad-7t100) which is a Chinese sorta tablet imported re-branded and sold in India. The tablet one day stopped from booting and the repair man put some generic rom onto it. But now the problem is the Wifi is not working, so i am thinking about flashing my own Rom. But it seems that i need to know the chip set which i am unable to find.  so can some one provide me some insight. I am very much looking forward to flash cyanogen mod onto it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

1. [To locate firmware for Zebpad](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f906/all-zebronics-tab-fidmware-links-1763885/). Post #4
2. [Manual from Zebronics, steps needed for upgrade](http://zebronics.info/downloads/Zebpad/Zebpad_7t100/zebpad%207t100_upgrade_guide.pdf). Viewable or downloadable .PDF

*source*:

https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=zebpad+7t100#q=zebpad+7t100+firmware+download

---

Here is an extra link for Zebpad 7t100 - http://zebronics.com/download-drivers/

As of this moment, I haven't found out the WiFi chipset. Will edit when I do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. it has been a while and i got the job done by a localite techy.